# nginx access location path within the location block

Tags: php, apache, http, web, nginx

I have this location block in nginx config

```
location /admin {
    rewrite ^/admin/users/(.*).html$ /users.php?page=$1 last;
    rewrite ^/admin/login$ /login.php last;
    rewrite ^/admin/upload$ /upload.php last;
}
```

Now, it has more than those 3 rewrites in it, is there a way to replace the common part which is "/admin" so that it looks back at the location $path ("/admin")?

I had a look at the docs but couldn't see anything related, Apache has the RewriteBase flag which is not supported in nginx.

Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
location /admin/ {
    rewrite ^/admin(.+) $1;
    rewrite ^/users/(.*).html$ /users.php?page=$1 last;
    rewrite ^/login$ /login.php last;
    rewrite ^/upload$ /upload.php last;
}
```